# Merge the subdomain and subdomains tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[subdomains](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/subdomains) seems to be a little-used and description-free tag for stuff which  [subdomain](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/subdomain) fits well (ie, DNS subdomain-related issues).

I would propose merging [subdomains](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/subdomains) into [subdomain](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/subdomain).

**Edit**: OK, it's been 10 days, and there seems to be good support for this judging by the voting.

But I've never suggested a tag merge before.  Is there some kind of ground work I should have done before mooting the merge, and my failure to have done this is causing a stunned silence?  Or is it that cleanup merges are low-priority, and I should just sit tight because it'll be got to in the fullness of time?  All disambiguation gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Needs an answer so here's one - this is done.